# I am getting error, when I run my npx command

Tags: node.js, npm

I wanted check if my game was working or not.

```bash
npx kah9a-cli-number-gussing-game
```

This is the error!

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No versions available for kah9a-cli-number-gussing-game

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jhoot\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-27T18_53_37_782Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

[`npx` runs scripts from packages that exist on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) (unless those scripts already exist locally).

You're trying to execute a script from the package [`kah9a-cli-number-gussing-game`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kah9a-cli-number-gussing-game), which, if you click on the link right there, you'll find doesn't exist.

Comment: so, are you saying that my the game I created and published on npm, has never published?

Comment: I'm saying that there's no package by that name. I don't know how you've created or published it, but there's no package by that name.